# how to load two different dynamic tableview cells in same UITableViewVibrantCell

Tags: ios, swift4.2

I have been trying two add two dynamic cells to a UITableView based on server response which will be having two scenarios.If the trip has been cancelled then that perticularcell should load one cell.If the trip has been completed then that cell should load the second cell.Can any one help me to load these cells based on server status.Thankyou In advance.

Comment: can you show your requirement we can give you an idea

Answer (score 1):

you should use stack view vertical and dynamic tableview cell height.
it means in your stack view you have 2 or more views.
the tableview cell height is dynamic so when you hidden first view the second view showing and the stack view size fixed.

so use below code in viewDidLoad to set the height of table view automatically:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = YourTableViewHeight
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

hope to helping you